# web server should be kept out of load balancer to perform app pool recycle? or its ok to perform the recycle of the app pool directly?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver, amazon-elb, elastic-load-balancer

Currently in our office when ever there is a spike in cpu or memory we keep that particular server on maintenance on load balancer and then perform app pool recycle. so this process is consuming time of ours. please let me know what happens when we dont keep the server out of LB while performing the recycle and can we do the recycle without keeping the server out of LB?

Thanks for your answers. if we can do as asked above then it will save lot of our time as we can schedule the recycle.

Comment: If you recycle app pool while keeping server in the load balancer the requests, going to that server during recycle, will fail and users or API consumers of application will receive unexpected response. You can keep one server on stand by mode and swap it with the faulty server quickly. Then recycle the app pool on faulty server and keep it ready to so the you can swap it with some other faulty server later.